# Convert survey data into graph

Tags: r, survey, network-analysis

I need to convert a dataframe into a matrix; I have a dataframe made of n row corresponding to a each employee, a variable that express which of the 12 department the employee works in (CDA, Marketing, Finance...) and 12 variables that express the numbers of time that the subject contact each department.

| id | department | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | l | m | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 6 | 8 | 4 | 6 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | b | 5 | 4 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 8 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | b | 1 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 4 | 6 | 6 | 8 | 4 | 2 | 6 | 5 |

I've just shown 3 of 100 rows as example. What I need is this:

|  | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | l | m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| b | 6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Ecc.......

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_by()` and `summarise()` from the `dplyr` package to accomplish this.  You can `group_by(department)` which will do whatever operations you specify within the department.  Then, you can use `summarise(across(a:n, sum))` which will sum the values for each variable a, b, c, ..., n in turn retaining all of those columns.

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, 
  text = "id    department  a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   l   m   n
1   a   2   4   5   1   1   0   6   8   4   6   2   1
2   b   5   4   5   2   3   0   5   5   4   8   4   5
3   b   1   2   5   0   4   6   6   8   4   2   6   5")

dat %>% 
  group_by(department) %>% 
  summarise(across(a:n, sum))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 13
#>   department     a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     l     m
#>   <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 a              2     4     5     1     1     0     6     8     4     6     2
#> 2 b              6     6    10     2     7     6    11    13     8    10    10
#> # … with 1 more variable: n <int>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>